# retainAll in java is very slow... Is there a method which is faster?

Tags: java, performance, arraylist

I have a project for the university which is «create a bilingual dictionary with a comparison of two texts (the second is a translation of the first).

There are 3 length of texts to test our program. With the small, the output is produced in less than 1 second, with the medium 45 seconds and with the large it’s like 85 minutes.

NetBeans says that the longest method is «retainAll» on an ArrayList. Is there any faster method ?

Edit : a little piece of code, I have to check the correlation index for each word/translation.

```
double ens1= list2.size();
double ens2=test.size();
//intersection of the both list
list2.retainAll(test);
//size of the intersection
double long_fin=list2.size();
//correlation index
correlation=(long_fin/(Math.sqrt(ens1*ens2)));
```

Comment: Please show some code. Also, I guess you are using the wrong DS, if you want to search often, use a Set or a Map

Answer (score 3):

Use `Set` instead of `List`. This removes the complexity a lot.

Alternatively you can sort both lists, and in one loop implement a retain-all.

*(An additional comment: use `int` instead of `double` - that grinds on the nerves of us safe-typing developers.)*

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! My both lists were already sorted, so I use a custom retainAll (with binary search), it’s really more efficient.

Comment: Using sets really help. A lot! I replaced a couple of lists with sets, which reduced the time it took to call retainAll on 2 lists with roughly 500.000 integers each from 15 minutes to 8 seconds.

Comment: @BjørnStenfeldt thanks, actual statistics really speak. From quadratic complexity to linear complexity or such. We Java programmers often fall in the trap that every collection looks like a `List`.